# I am confused over whether to use "what" or "that"

Tags: free-relative-clauses, relative-clauses

The sentence goes one of these two ways:

> "He knows **WHAT** other teachers don't know"

or perhaps:

> "He knows **things THAT** others teachers don't"

Which is better to use - WHAT or THAT? Are they both grammatically acceptable?

Comment: I might use the first one if I was explaining why he was such a great teacher. I might be more inclined to use the second one if I was explaining that he was aware of some impending shakeup at the school before other teachers knew the facts. But that's a blurry dividing line.

Answer (score 5):

Both are grammatical, but they mean somewhat different things.

> **He knows what other teachers don't know.**

In this the clause *what other teachers don't know* is a "free relative clause", which acts all-by-itself as a noun clause. In this case it acts as the Direct Object of the verb *knows*.

> He knows [<sub>DirObj</sub> what other teachers don't know.]

In another sentence it might act as the Subject:

> [<sub>Subj</sub> What other teachers don't know] is how to communicate with their students.

If it is not specifically modified, it will be understood to mean **everything** which other teachers don't know.

> He knows all the things which other teachers don't know.

---

> **He knows things that other teachers don't know.**

In this the clause *that other teachers don't know* is a "bound relative clause". It might also be written ***which*** other teachers don't know. This cannot stand alone: it has to follow a noun phrase (in this case *things*) which it modifies. In effect, it acts as an "adjective". As FumbleFingers points out, if you said ***the*** things here it would be equivalent to  your first sentence; but the version without the *the* says that there are merely some things which he knows but other teachers don't:

> He knows some things which other teachers don't know.

Comment: You don't seem to have mentioned it, but to me, **that** or **which** is effectively optional in this context. I find it interesting that, as you say, in the "bound relative clause" version, **things** inevitably implies ***some**, but not **all** things*. But if it's ***the** things*, that implies *everything* to me. So I've been treating my moribund [kundabuffer](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_kundabuffer) with [the only beer that "grammatically" should help](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFn-jSSrBPQ), but I think those adverts are lies - it still ain't working properly!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did mention the which/that option. But your point about *the* is spot on -- fixed. As for advertising, that's highly-compensated abuse of language.

Answer (score 1):

The two have very different interpretations, both make grammatical sense.

- "He knows what other teachers don't" means "He possesses knowledge that
  other teachers don't have".
- "He knows that other teachers don't" means "He is aware that other teackers don't (do something)".

Comment: I think not: OP's second sentence is "He knows **things** that other teachers don't".